# Cut string url in javascript

Tags: javascript, split, substring

I have a string like below

```
var indicator = -65(www.anyweb.com)
```

the number -65 can be any number too. How can I take out only the web url separately in javascript?

Comment: I have no idea what `-65(www.anyweb.com)` means in JavaScript? Is this an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the variable is a string?

Comment: I'm pulling this whole string from backend. What I need to do was to take out only the url and assign as hyperlink to value -65(for example)

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the string after '(' and before ')'

```
var str = "-65(www.anyweb.com)";
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this example for string operations




var data = "-65(www.anyweb.com)";
var url = data.slice(data.indexOf('(')+1 ,data.indexOf(')'));    console.log("URL :: ",url);
```

Comment: When there is no url in data such as only -65, this returns -6 which is not correct for my case

Answer (score 0):

```js
var domain = /\((.*?)\)/.exec("-65(www.anyweb.com)")[1];
console.log(domain);
```

---

The regex above will create a group with anything that's inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple string operations:

```
var str = "-65(www.anyweb.com)";
var url = "N/A";

// Find indices of open and close parentheses
var open  = str.indexOf("(");
var close = str.lastIndexOf(")");

// If they were found then extract the URL from the string
if (open !== -1 && close !== -1) {
    url = str.substring(open + 1, close);
}
console.log(url);
```

If you are more inclined to use regular expressions then this should do it:

```
var str = "-65(www.anyweb.com)";
var regex = /\((.*?)\)/; // Capture URL inside parentheses
var result = regex.exec(str); // Execute the regex against the string
var url = "N/A";

// If the URL was matched then assign it to the variable
if (result[1] !== undefined) {
  url = result[1];
}
console.log(url);
```

You can also simply replace the stuff that you do not want:

```
var str = "-65(www.anyweb.com)";
str = str.replace(/^.*\(/, ""); // Remove everything before URL
str = str.replace(/\).*$/, "");  // Remove everything after URL
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Example 1 : 
var data = "-65(www.anyweb.com)";

if(data.indexOf('(')!=-1){
var url = data.slice(data.indexOf('(')+1 ,data.indexOf(')'));
} 
console.log("URL :: ",url);

Example 2 : 
var data = "-65";

if(data.indexOf('(')!=-1){
var url = data.slice(data.indexOf('(')+1 ,data.indexOf(')'));
} 
console.log("URL :: ",url);

Example 3 : 
var data = "-65(www.anyweb.com)6764872";

if(data.indexOf('(')!=-1){
var url = data.slice(data.indexOf('(')+1 ,data.indexOf(')'));
} 
console.log("URL :: ",url);
```